# Gtk# OnButtonPressEvent is not working

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am pretty new to Gtk#, so please be patient. I want to create my own widget which will have two functions: draw what you want, and report if user clicked at this widget.

My code in method:

```
protected override bool OnExposeEvent (Gdk.EventExpose args)
{
    // this works!
}
```

is fully working, but the code in following method:

```
protected override bool OnButtonPressEvent (Gdk.EventButton ev)
{
    // this is not working at all :-(
    Console.WriteLine("test!");
    return base.OnButtonPressEvent (ev);
}
```

is not working. Both methods are some responses on events, so why `OnButtonPressEvent` is not called when I click at widget??

I have another widget which inherits from Table, but Buttons in Table works well, so why is there this problem?

Thanks in  advance...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a signal to your button like this:

```
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               //some stuff
            }
```

It will work correctly. This is the way you must use Button widget. Sometimes it's depending how you layout your app, some widgets can be on your button and it can make unwanted behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use **Button Clicked signal** instead of Button Pressed.  That's what I use with all of my buttons and it works as expected.